compatibility issues with java and kotlin i think?
i am jumping between gradle files,vscode settings,android studio and path variables but to no avail it doesn't work i am working on a flutter app with firebase PS C:\Users*\Downloads\a**> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sign_in_with_apple:compileDebugKotlin'.


'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

changing settings.json
{
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off"
    },
    "dart.addSdkToTerminalPath": true,
    "dart.sdkPaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\Salil\\Downloads\\YoutubeClone-Flutter-master\\youtubeclone_env\\Scripts\\flutter"
    ],
    "dart.sdkPath": null,
    "githubPullRequests.pullBranch": "never",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "plaintext": true,
        "markdown": false,
        "scminput": false,
        "cpp": true
    },
    "vs-kubernetes": {
        "vscode-kubernetes.helm-path.windows": "C:\\Users\\Salil\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\helm\\windows-amd64\\helm.exe",
        "vscode-kubernetes.kubectl-path.windows": "C:\\Users\\Salil\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\kubectl\\kubectl.exe",
        "vscode-kubernetes.minikube-path.windows": "C:\\Users\\Salil\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\minikube\\windows-amd64\\minikube.exe"
    },
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtDesignStudio\\qt6_design_studio_reduced_version\\include\\QtGui"
    ],
    "cmake.additionalCompilerSearchDirs": [
        "C:/msys64/mingw32/bin",
        "C:/msys64/clang32/bin",
        "C:/msys64/clang64/bin",
        "C:/msys64/clangarm64/bin",
        "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin"
    ],
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "dart.flutterSdkPaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\Salil\\Downloads\\YoutubeClone-Flutter-master\\youtubeclone_env\\Scripts\\flutter\\bin"
    ],
    "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true,
    "java.debug.settings.vmArgs": "-Xmx4G -ea",
    "java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "",
    "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
        "-dart.sdkPath",
        "-dart.flutterSdkPath",
        "-java.configuration.runtimes",
        "-java.import.gradle.java.home",
        "-java.import.gradle.user.home",
        "-java.import.gradle.home",
        "-maven.executable.path",
        "-java.jdt.ls.java.home"
    ],
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "debug.javascript.debugByLinkOptions": "on",
    "[gradle]": {},
    "github.copilot.preferredAccount": "SalilHarit",
    "workbench.settings.applyToAllProfiles": [
        "java.import.gradle.java.home"
    ],
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
    },
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.rulers": [
        {
            "column": 80,
            "color": "#00FF0010"
        },
        {
            "column": 100,
            "color": "#BDB76B15"
        },
        {
            "column": 120,
            "color": "#FA807219"
        }
    ],
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.includeComments": true,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Default Dark Modern]": {
            "tab.activeBorderTop": "#00FF00",
            "tab.unfocusedActiveBorderTop": "#00FF0088",
            "textCodeBlock.background": "#00000055"
        },
        "editor.wordHighlightStrongBorder": "#FF6347",
        "editor.wordHighlightBorder": "#FFD700",
        "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#A9A9A9"
    },
    "workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true,
    "workbench.tree.indent": 20,
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "[bat]": {
        "files.eol": "\r\n"
    },
    "emmet.variables": {
        "lang": "en"
    },
    "cSpell.diagnosticLevel": "Hint",
    "trailing-spaces.backgroundColor": "rgba(255,0,0,0.1)",
    "trailing-spaces.includeEmptyLines": false,
    "terminal.integrated.tabs.hideCondition": "never",
    "terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false,
    "java.configuration.detectJdksAtStart": false,
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.debug.settings.hotCodeReplace": "auto",
    "java.dependency.packagePresentation": "hierarchical",
    "java.sources.organizeImports.staticStarThreshold": 1,
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
{
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot",
            "default": true
            
            
},

        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-8.0.422.5-hotspot",
            
        },

        {
            "name": "JavaSE-22",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-22",
            
        }
    ],
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {

        "JavaSE-17": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "env": {
                "PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot\\bin;${env:PATH}",
                "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot"
            },
            "path": "cmd"
        },

    },
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {
        "path": "cmd"
    },
    "java.test.config": {
        "vmArgs": [
            "-Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8",
            "-Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8"
        ]
    },
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot",
        "PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot\\bin;${env:PATH}"
    },
    "maven.terminal.customEnv": [
        {
            "environmentVariable": "JAVA_HOME",
            "value": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot"
        }
    ],
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
    "java.project.outputPath": "",
    "java.imports.gradle.wrapper.checksums": [],
    "files.associations": {
        "*.gradle": "dart"
    },
    "java.maven.downloadSources": true,
    "java.import.gradle.version": "",
    "[java-properties]": {},
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.12.7-hotspot\\bin",
}

and app/build.gradle



plugins {
   id "com.android.application"
   id "kotlin-android"
   id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
   id "com.google.gms.google-services"  // Google Services plugin

   
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1.0'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mycompany.astrovista"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        versionCode 167
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
            keyAlias '**'
            keyPassword ''
            storeFile file('')
            storePassword ''
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
                        ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'
            }
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.10"
}


settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.4.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.10" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false  // Google Services plugin
    
}

include ":app"

android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
        project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}


tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



remember to put it inside this block
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId 
        minSdkVersion 
        targetSdkVersion 
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        versionCode 167
                compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
